# Filtering connections by group or label

Tags: google-api-python-client, google-people-api

The Google People API allows you to get a list of all contacts:

```
  resultset = service.people().connections().list(
  resourceName='people/me',
  pageSize=100,
  personFields=('names,emailAddresses,organizations,photos,phoneNumbers'))
```

Is there any way to filter the results by Contact Group? I couldn't find the [source code](https://google.github.io/google-api-python-client/docs/epy/index.html) for the list method ...

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a way to filter by contact group in the list call. The two options you have are:

1. Do a [get on the contact group](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/contactGroups/get) to get a list of personIds in the contact group. Then do a [batchget](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people/getBatchGet) to get all the personIds.
2. Get all contacts and filter them yourself

Comment: Thanks Amos.
I also found a field from personFields that is not documented: "etag" - is this the Contact Group ID?